# Am I not freeing memory somewhere?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind

I have a program that reads from a file and stores items in the queue then prints them back out. I am getting this from valgrind:

```
 HEAP SUMMARY:
     in use at exit: 302 bytes in 14 blocks
   total heap usage: 30 allocs, 16 frees, 1,230 bytes allocated

 302 bytes in 14 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
    at 0x4A05FDE: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
    by 0x372167FB41: strdup (strdup.c:43)
    by 0x400A6A: addtoqueue(main.c:30)
    by 0x400B5A: addfiletoqueue(main.c:45)
    by 0x400C27: main (main.c:62)

 LEAK SUMMARY:
    definitely lost: 302 bytes in 14 blocks
    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

Line 62 of main.c

```
addfiletoqueue (queue, argv[argi]);
```

Line 45 of main.c

```
addtoqueue (queue, file, filename);
```

Line 30 of main.c

```
readline = strdup (buffer);
assert (readline != NULL);
queue_add (queue, readline);
```

Do I need to free readline?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, [`strdup()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup) dynamically allocates memory which you must `free()`. From the linked reference page:

> The strdup() function returns a pointer to a new string which is a duplicate of the string s. **Memory for the new string is obtained with malloc(3), and can be freed with free(3).**

Answer (score 5):

> Do I need to free readline?

Yes.  The [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup) for `strdup` states that it dynamically allocates memory for its return value.  You must therefore call `free` on this somewhere later in your program.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you need to free it when you're done using it.

This is probably not in `addfiletoqueue()`, but when the program exits. However, the diagnostic saying that the memory is "definitely lost" implies that there might be more problems, perhaps you lose the pointer(s) along the way.

Basically `strdup()` is just calling `malloc()` and `strcpy()` for you, so it is allocating memory off the heap which you need to `free()` when you're done using.

Also, `readline` is a very bad variable name since it's also a pretty standardized [function name](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?readline+3).

Comment: My readline variable only exists within the scope of a for loop and when trying to free it I get a bunch more errors about invalid read sizes and free'd addresses.

Comment: The scope of the variable doesn't matter, the memory it points at must be given to the `free()` function in order to be de-allocated. That the pointer variable itself goes of out of scope when the loop ends doesn't matter.

Comment: I free (queue) which contains the nodes and lines, but does free, free all that? How do I free the memory of readline later on if I can't use it as a argument?

Answer (score 1):

The strdup() function returns a pointer to a new string which is a duplicate
of the string s.  Memory for the new string is obtained with malloc(3), and
can be freed with free(3)

http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/strdup.3.html

Valgrind "definitely lost in loss record" shows your code leak memory! So you need to take care of such error from valgrind...